# Python - ¿Como puedo dibujar figuras geométricas con matrices?

Tags: python, matrices, fórmulas-de-matriz

Hola mi duda es la siguiente, puedo realizar figuras geométricas con ecuaciones geométricas en una matriz solo con signos?
-> pura matrices, no pylab o pygame

Estaba en un proyecto tratando de realizar figuras geométricas pero me trabe y no puedo avanzar el proyecto trata en realizar un programa en python que permita ingresar ecuaciones geométricas y a partir de estas debo que dicha ecuación se dibuje en la matriz.

Mis avances:

```
alto = 12 #42
largo = 12 #82

#CREANDO MATRIZ
matriz = []
for i in range(alto): #ALTO
    matriz.append([])
    for j in range(largo): #LARGO
        matriz[i].append(" ")


#GENERAR LINEAS DEL PRIMER CUADRANTE
for i in range(alto): #ALTO
    if i != alto - 1:
        for j in range(largo): #LARGO
            if j is 0:
                matriz[i][j] = "."
    else:
        for j in range(largo): #LARGO
            matriz[i][j] = "."

for i in range(10):
    #A UN LADO
    matriz[10 - i][1 + i] = "X"
    #RECTO
    #matriz[10][1 + i] = "X"

#IMPRIMIR MATRIZ
for i in range(alto):
    for j in range(largo): #LARGO
        print(matriz[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias.

Comment: https://github.com/nschloe/asciiplotlib/ podría servir? O https://github.com/kroitor/asciichart que, aunque dice que está hecho en node.js tiene un _port_ a python?

Comment: La mejor librería para estos casos es matplotlib que simula los plots de Matlab: https://matplotlib.org/

Answer (score 3):

Steven, lo que necesitas hacer es modificar la lógica en el `for` donde generas las rectas de tu ejemplo para que utilice tanto x como y (si es que la ecuación lo requiere, por ejemplo, te muestro cómo sería una circunferencia de radio 2), y además, pasar por cada punto x,y (es decir 0,0; 0,1; 0,2; 1,0 ; etc.), por lo que te serviría el módulo `product` de `itertools`. Así, solo reemplazas la ecuación que necesitas con un `if`

Ejemplo:

```
import itertools
for x,y in itertools.product(range(12),range(12)):
    if (x-6)**2 + (y-6)**2 == 4:
        matriz[x][y] = "X"
```

Que daría como resultado

```
.
.
.
.
.           X
.
.       X       X
.
.           X
.
.
. . . . . . . . . . . .
```

El otro problema aquí sería la resolución, que se puede solucionar si le damos una mano a la ecuación, y aceptamos no solo el 4 (el radio al cuadrado, en la ecuación), sino un rango de valores (escogí de 4 a 7 porque si le doy 1, incluiría una circunferencia de r=1, y si le doy 9, incluiría una de r = 3), para esto tendrías que aplicar matemática, no estoy seguro de cómo funciona exactamente.

```
for x,y in itertools.product(range(12),range(12)):
    ecuacion = (x-6)**2 + (y-6)**2
    if ecuacion >= 4 and ecuacion <= 7:
        matriz[x][y] = "X"
```

Que nos daría como resultado

```
.
.
.
.
.         X X X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.         X X X
.
.
. . . . . . . . . . . .
```

El problema debería aminorarse siempre que hagas más grande tu matriz, y las ecuaciones.

Un último ejemplo con una elipse, y una matriz un poco más grande

```
for x,y in itertools.product(range(20),range(20)):
    ecuacion = (x-8)**2/6 + (y-6)**2
    if ecuacion >= 4 and ecuacion <= 9:
        matriz[x][y] = "X"
```

Resultado

```
.
.           X
.         X X X
.       X X X X X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.     X X       X X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X       X
.       X X X X X
.         X X X
. . . . . . X . . . . . .
```

Otra opción es que le hagas una suerte de "zoom" y al momento de asignar la X e Y en la matriz, asignas X*2 o Y*2 (o cualquier otro número, entero), lo cual haría que efectivamente cada punto en la matriz sea 0.5 unidades, en lugar de 1 como es ahora.

Para una recta, tu for loop funcionaria mas o menos asi

```
# Tuplas: Indice 0 = x, indice 1 = y
punto1 = (2,2)
punto2 = (0,3)

pendiente = (punto1[1] - punto2[1]) / (punto1[0] - punto2[0]) # m = y2-y1 / x2-x1
for x,y in itertools.product(range(20),range(20)):
    ecuacion = pendiente * (punto1[0] - x) + punto1[1] # Ecuacion y-y1 = m (x1-x)
    if abs(ecuacion) >= (y-0.5) and abs(ecuacion) <= (y+0.5):
        try:
            matriz[x][y] = "X"
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro! Ya me salio con la ecuacion de la recta pero todabia tengo que averiguar como centrar el circulo ejeje pero Muchas gracias ;D

Comment: Por nada, para mover la circunferencia puedes hacer la resta en el x o el y (x-10 por ejemplo, dentro de la potencia), de repente puedes usar el largo / alto entre 2?

Comment: Amigo sabes como podria hacerle a la recta para que solo solicite dos cordenadas y que imprima en esa direccion. ps: Lo del circulo ya me funciono!!!!.

Comment: Steven, lo agregué a la rpta. Ahi lo dejo, pero solo es cosa de usar geometría analítica y dejar una variable a la derecha (en este caso, la ecuación era y-y1 = m(x1-x), entonces moví el y1. En la circunferencia, la ecuación es (y-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2, por lo que no había nada que cambiar (el r ya está solo))

Comment: Muchas gracias! :)